# Blazor is not "compiling" all of my .razor pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

OP: Why can't Blazor build and find a page almost identical to another one

Blazor server-side app (3.1).  I have two components, a ListX.razor and a ListY.razor.  ListX is under Pages\X\Listx.razor and ListY is under Pages\Y\ListY.razor

Both start with @page directives (@page "/ListX"; @page "/ListY").  When I look in obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/RazorDeclaration/Pages/ListX folder, I find a ListX.razor.g.cs file.  When I look in the obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/RazorDeclaration/Pages/ListY folder, there is nothing.

I have two NavLinks: `<NavLink class="nav-link" href="listx"> and a <NavLink class="nav-link" href="listy">`.

ListX displays just fine, ListY gives me "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." which is the NotFound component.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

After getting a little grayer and little more frustrated, I looked at the .csproj file on a whim.  Lo and behold, there was a <compile remove= for the folders and files I was having trouble with.  Cleaned up the .csproj file and everything now builds and runs just fine.

Moral of the story:  If you are seeing something really weird, go back to basics.  If that doesn't help go *further* back to basics.

In this case, reviewing Blazor routing and comparing the two components wasn't working.  So, I went back to "what might prevent a file from being compiled or included in the build output" and voila!